# Having trouble finding the highest average

Tags: java, text, average

I have two problems with my code below. I am working with averages.

First, I am struggling to how to find which week has the highest average and then outputting what that average is.

Second, there are 39 weeks on the txt file, but only 38 are counted when running my code.

This is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TemperaturesWeek2 {
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException {
        int count=0;
        int counts=0;

        File inputFile = new File ("C:/Users/Phillip/Documents/Temp/temperatures.txt .txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);


        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            count++;
            scan.nextLine();

            String words = scan.next();

            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
            double num2 = scan.nextDouble();
            double num3 = scan.nextDouble();
            double num4 = scan.nextDouble();
            double num5 = scan.nextDouble();
            double num6 = scan.nextDouble();
            double num7 = scan.nextDouble();

            double average = (num1 + num2 + num3+ num4+ num5+ num6+ num7) / 7;

            if(average >= 90) { 
                counts++; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Temperature Statistics:");  
        System.out.println("Number of weeks: " + count);
        System.out.println("Weeks with an average temperature of 90 or above: " + counts);
        System.out.println("Highest average weekly temperature:");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra ending bracket here you don't need `if(average >= 90) { counts++; }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to skip the first line of the file, since you call `scan.nextLine();` before reading the various doubles.

A simple solution to finding out which week has the highest average would be to add two more variables in your code, for example:

```
int highestWeek = 0;
double highestAverage = 0;
```

and then storing the desired values in your while loop using an if statement (there are plenty of ways you could decide what the max is, you can use the Math class or maybe store everything in an array if you want to manipulate the data more later). For exaple:

```
if (average>highestAverage)
{
      highestAverage=average;
      highestWeek=count;
}
```

NOTE: This will ignore the case where multiple weeks have the highest average.

Comment: how would you do it using math class because i have been trying Math.max( , ) but dont know what values to put in?

Comment: You'd need to do something like  highestAverage = Math.max(highestAverage, average); (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(double, double))

Comment: why does it count 38 weeks instead of 39 tho im still getting that

Comment: Did you remove the scan.nextLine(); ? You skip the first line of the file, the way you have it in your code.